# Как избавиться от дочерних селекторов на сайте

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Как избавиться от дочерних селекторов на сайте, при этом не переписывая полностью 30 страниц.
На страницах возможно присутствие блоков с других страниц.
Эти блоки имеют свой стиль в .css который относится к странице, где был написан блок изначально.

Answer (score 1):

Всё зависит от применяющегося у Вас шаблонизатора.
Будьте любезны указать детали, и, если это возможно, фрагменты кода.

***Вариант 1*** опираемся на тег `<p class="text-1">` (будет затронуты ВСЕ теги span, расположенные внутри `<p class="text-1">`):

```
// regexp
<p class="text-1">([^<]+)<span>

// replacement
<p class="text-1">$1<span class="catalog__line-1_span">
```

[image: до замены]
[image: после замены]

***Вариант 2*** более правильный - должен затронуть все теги `<p class="name_door catalog__link">`, находящиеся в `.catalog__line-1_product border_left-0`, но по непонятной для меня причине не работает в VSC:

вот [ссылка](https://regex101.com/r/DOhTUJ/4)

```
// regexp
~(<div class="catalog__line-1_product border_left-0">)([^<]*?)<p class="([^"]*)([\s\S]*?)(<\/div>)~g

// replacement 
$1$2<p class="new_class"$4$5
```

Если кто поправит - буду признателен.

Comment: Что такое шаблонизатор?) Первый раз о таком слышу /Стыдно/
`<div class="catalog__line-1_product border_left-0">
  <p class="text-1">
    text
      <span>text</span>
    text
  </p>
  <p class="name_door catalog__link">text</p>
  <p class="text-2">text</p>
</div>`
Допустим этот блок
Вместо того, чтобы быть умным и писать каждому блоку/элементу свой уникальный класс, я использовал дочерние селекторы для стилей.
Допустим 
`.catalog__line-1_product > .text-1 > span {
  color: red;
}`

Comment: Хм.. а на что хотите заменить? И каким редактором пользуетесь?

Comment: сейчас попробую регулярку какую-нибудь накидать.

Comment: Visual studio code. 
Должно быть не `.catalog__line-1_product > .text-1 > span { color: red; }`, а 
`.catalog__line-1_span { color: red; }`